# OpenCV - training new LatentSVMDetector Models

Tags: opencv

I haven't found any method to train new latent svm detector models using openCV. I'm currently using the existing models given in the xml files, but I would like to train my own.

Is there any method for doing so?

Thank you,

Gil.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of now only DPM-detection is implemented in OpenCV, not training. 
If you want to train your own models, the most reliable approach is to use Felzenszwalb's and Girshick's matlab code (most of the heavy stuff is implemented in C) <strike>(http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/latent/)</strike>(http://www.rossgirshick.info/latent/) It is reliable and works reasonably fast

If you want to do it in C-only, there is an implementation here (http://libccv.org/doc/doc-dpm/) that I haven't tried myself.

Comment: Are you saying that I can use "Discriminatively trained deformable part models" to train a latent SVM and then load the file in OpenCV and use it to detect my object?

Comment: @Crash-ID, the author's code can only be used to train a matlab model. You cannot use that model in OpenCV. I am also looking for a code that converts the matlab model to the xml format in opencv.

Comment: @killogre you 'might' be able to use mat2opencvxml.m found here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_extra/tree/master/testdata/cv/dpm to do the conversion (I haven't tried, so I don't know for sure)

Comment: @kamjagin The first link is not working now. The second was explaining how to train the matlab model, and nothin about converting it to opencv xml model.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a function in the octave version of the author's code here
([Octave Version of DPM](https://github.com/Jiaolong/dpm-octave)). It is in step #5,

`mat2opencvxml('./INRIA/inriaperson_final.mat', 'inriaperson_cascade_cv.xml');`

I will try it and let you know about the result.

---

**EDIT**

- I tried to convert the `.mat` file from the octave version i mentioned before to `.xml` file, and compared the result with the built in opencv `.xml` model and the construction of the 2 xmls was different (tags, #components,..), it seems that this version of octave dpm generates xml files for later opencv version (i am using 2.4).
- VOC-release3.1 is the one matches opencv2.4.14. I tried to convert the already trained model from this version using mat2xml function available in opencv and the result xml file is successfully loaded and working with opencv. Here are some helpful links:

[mat2xml code](https://github.com/malcolmreynolds/OpenCV/blob/master/opencv_extra/testdata/cv/latentsvmdetector/mat2xml.m)

[VOC-release-3.1](https://cs.brown.edu/~pff/latent-release3/)

[How To Train DPM on a New Object](https://github.com/rbgirshick/voc-dpm/issues/16)